# Finding Measuring Points in three-point perspective drawing

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

In his Complete Guide to Perspective Drawing (page 39), Craig Attebery places Measuring Points of two-point perspective in a line perperdicular to that crossing the Station Point and the Center of Vision:

[image]

LVP, RVP = Left/Right Vanishing Points

LMP, LVP = Left/Right Measuring Points

SP = Station Point

Later, on page 179, the author uses a different method for three-point perspective, in which the Measuring Point line does not cross the Center of Vision/Station Point line at a 90° angle. I would like to know why.

[image]

LVP, RVP, VVP = Left/Right/Vertical Vanishing Points

LMP, LVP, VVP = Left/Right/Vertical Measuring Points

LSP = Left Station Point

Note: Notation in red was added by me

Comment: Note that in projective geometry (at least as I know it) there is no distance measure! I am not familiar with the concepts of station point or measuring point, I'm assuming station point to be one that is not changed by the projection? How is the measuring point used?

Comment: Station Point is where are the eyes of the observer. This is obtained by folding the part of the plane behind the picture. For a better understanding of how this is done, see Robertson and Bertling's How to Draw.

Comment: Regarding the Measuring Point, each Vanishing Point has its Measuring Point, which is a second vanishing point. The lines of these two points, alongside a third one, form an isosceles triangle, which is used to obtain measures in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

The method is the same. In one- and two-point perspective, the vertical vanishing point is at infinity, which effectively means that the left reference line (i.e., the line through LVP and CV) coincides with the horizon.

In other words, when you say that Attebery "places Measuring Points of two-point perspective in a line perpendicular to that crossing the Station Point and the Center of Vision", this is true, but it's a coincidence. (Note that it's also not the way he describes it.)

When learning perspective, we start with one-point, and work up to three-point perspective, since it's much easier to gradually introduce concepts this way. One- and two-point perspective are convenient because a lot of things line up nicely—but it's this very convenience that can lead to confusion.